# Sorting a list of objects by a string field by letter then number?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What's a good way to sort an object with a list of strings that are alphanumeric?

I have a list of objects like this.

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string A {get; set;}
}

var listOfItems = new List<ObjectA>() 
{ 
    new ObjectA() { A = "0000003F" }, 
    new ObjectA() { A = "00000035" }, 
    new ObjectA() { A = "TESTTEST" }, 
    new ObjectA() { A = "000633BX" } 
};
```

and when I use LINQ to sort these:

```
var sortedList = listOfItems.OrderBy(x => x.A);
```

I get this list:

```
00000035
0000003F
D0000033
12345678
0A000033
000633BX
TESTTEST
```

But would like this instead:

```
D0000033
TESTTEST
0A000033
0000003F
00000035
000633BX
12345678
```

How can I make the sorting be done by letter then number?

String is of fixed length at 8 characters all alphanumeric no special characters.

Comment: Please provide a larger sample set in your inputs (and output). It must include strings of various lengths, as well as strings where the first letter is not at the first position in the string. It must include entries where the entries differ only by the case of the first character.

Comment: What are the rules for that sort order??

Comment: question, what if there is "abcde", will "testtest" be first or "abcde"?

Comment: It must include strings of various lengths. It must include entries where the entries differ only by the case of the first character. _This is important to understand exactly what your rules are, since your specification is overly vague._

Comment: @mjwills I'm trying to emulate a process and it seems to sort things in this manner. Otherwise I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: I'm assuming you have no access to how that process actually works or you would crack that code open and follow the logic. Can you express the *semantics* of that process? So far, capital letters sort before digits, but there's insufficient data to be sure that that's the actual rule.

Comment: It must include entries where the entries differ only by the case of the first character.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm for ordering isn't clear, but here's an approach you can take. First, define a custom comparer:

```
public class ObjectAComparer : IComparer<ObjectA>
{
    public int Compare(ObjectA x, ObjectA y)
    {
        // Quite possibly not the ordering logic you want. Change as needed.
        // "IsNumber" means what you seem to have defined as numbers.
        bool xIsNumber = x.A.Any(c => char.IsNumber(c));
        bool yIsNumber = y.A.Any(c => char.IsNumber(c));

        bool sameKind = !(xIsNumber ^ yIsNumber);
        if (sameKind) return x.A.CompareTo(y.A); // Both numbers or both not numbers

        if (xIsNumber) return 1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the [overload of OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) that takes a comparer:

```
var sortedList = listOfItems.OrderBy(x => x, new ObjectAComparer());
```

Output:

```
TESTTEST 
00000035 
0000003F 
000633BX
```

Comment: You should compare char by char, because it doesn't generate the the expected output for the example list.

Comment: It matches what he had up there before he edited the post. His ordering rules aren't clear... he can fill in appropriate logic.

Comment: He edited the post 13 minutes before you posted the answer.

Comment: A) I wrote the answer on the side while attending a conference then posted it when I had a chance; B) It doesn't matter because the update still doesn't specify the sorting rules but only gives a more extended example, and he can insert whatever ordering logic he needs.